# Is there a Halacha that says that you shouldn’t stretch in public?

Tags: halacha, rabbis, mysticism-kabbalah, derech-eretz-manners, masechet-derech-eretz

BH

Is there a consept in Halacha that says that a person shouldn't stretch in public(ie. to keep it together in public)

Comment: Stretch your muscles??